# How to Tap on a button using adb c#

Tags: c#

I know to make my program tap on those buttons. I have to get its location.
but, I don't know how to get location manually or automatically.So please if you have any information to get the location of a button manually or automatically. will be glad.

[image: here is picture of example]

Comment: Are you trying to write an automated test for your gui?

Comment: @Fildor yes iam